# Getting page ID in a template that has no loop

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a form that collects data on a product and then puts the data into the wp_posts table and wp_postmeta table. I can build a permalink around the ID and if I then do a wp_redirect to this permalink WordPress should try to display the page.

The page's template is called listing.php, and it has no Loop.  Its only purpose is to display these product pages by placing the data in the wp_posts table and wp_postmeta table into various divs.  But I'm wondering how the template can get the ID of the page it's building so it can access the wp_posts table and wp_postmeta table. I'd like to do something like `$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() )` but the codex says you can only use `get_the_ID()` in the Loop and I don't have one of those. So how should I be doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most sound and reliable way to get the page ID of the current page is to make use og the queried object. The two functions `get_queried_object()` and `get_queried_object_id()` will hold the info of the current page (*on category, tag, taxonomy and author pages it will hold the current category, tag, term and author info respectively*)

To get the page id, simply use

```
$page_id = get_queried_object_id();
echo $page_id;
```

Comment: All three of these methods get the ID for me in my template with no Loop.  I suspect they want you to put it in the Loop so you're getting the ID of the current post the Loop is handling. For me I can put it anywhere because the template is only handling one page.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the post id from the global $post variable.

global $post;
echo $post->ID;

Comment: The codex says "$post contains data from the current post in The Loop."  Will it be valid when I don't have a Loop?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the data in the $post global is set before the page templates are even loaded, so it should have all the post information even though there isn't a loop.